# How do I show a loading indicator while app is launched?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I´m working in a cordova CLI multi-platform app project, that works fine on show a splash screen while app is launched. I need to add a label "wait, loading.." or a rotating spinner or something like, any suggestions ?

Adding

```
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true">
```

to config.xml has no effect

Answer (score 1):

You can try the opensourced [loading indicator](https://github.com/mobimentum/phonegap-plugin-loading-spinner) plugin, one of many.